# Understanding useState inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have the following simple app:

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("before setting ", count);
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log("set to ", count);
  }, []);
  return <div>hello</div>;
}
```

The expected result is:

```
before setting 0
set to 0
```

but the actual result is:

```
before setting 0
set to  0
before setting  0
set to  0
```

I do not understand two things:

1. why does the `useEffect` function run twice?
2. why does not setting the count value actually set it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `setCount()` does not update the `count` immediately: React batches these updates. If you want to log the new value of `count`, then use another `useEffect` hook that only has `count` in its dependency array.

Comment: 1.  If the `useEffect` is running twice with `[]` it's likely your in debug mode, recent versions of React added this `<React.StrictMode>`, in production this doesn't happen.

Comment: Re #1: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html Re #2: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: Thank you guys for the information. My questions are answered!